Failure on deploy of application .NET Core 6 in docker image at AWS App Runner
I am obtaining failure by deploying a .NET Core 6 docker image on AWS App Runner. Apparently, the publication works, however, I get the following error message, when access to the application URL: https://w2stuctfnn.us-east-1.awsapprunner.com/
"upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure, transport failure reason: delayed connect error: 113"

I am using the following code on dockerfile:

The logs of the publication in the App Runner are these:

Please, what should I correct so that the application is accessible by the URL?

Did you manage to figure this out? Were there any helpful details in the CloudWatch logs?
